# Navigation Gizmos on the right of the viewport are gone

Tags: interface

My navigation buttons with the zoom, pan, camera view and perspective buttons that are located on the right of the 3D viewport by default are gone.

How may i get it back?

[image: right options]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the *Viewport Gizmos* are enabled, and in the panel that the *Navigate* option is enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are **two** places to check. One is the Navigate checkbox accessed through the gizmos button, as shown in moonboots' answer.  This must be checked on.

The other is in Preferences (get there thru the gear button in the corner of the window pane), in Interface (topmost item in menu), in the Editors section.  There's a checkbox labelled Navigation Controls. This turn on/off the zoom, pan etc. navigation buttons.  But only if the gizmos button's checkbox is also on!

[image]